# Finding first and last occurrence of an element using binary search and effects in scala

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I've got functions with following signatures:

```scala
case class Sth(index: Long, str: String)

def fetch(n: Long): F[Sth] = ??? //implemented

def findFirstAndLast(min: Long, max: Long, str: String): F[(Long, Long)] = ???
```

I have certainty that `str` are grouped and groups don't occur twice.

For example this will be correct:

```scala
Sth(1, "a")
Sth(2, "a")
Sth(3, "b")
Sth(4, "b")
Sth(5, "b")
Sth(6, "c")
Sth(7, "d")
Sth(8, "d")
```

and that should be result of my function: `findFirstAndLast(1, 8, "b") = F((3, 5))`

But following case will never happen:

```scala
Sth(1, "a")
Sth(2, "b")
Sth(3, "b")
Sth(4, "a")
```

I tried to implement this but my brain stopped functioning when I've added the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by envisioning your algorithm as a recursive one, where there is some initial "state", and the algorithm can choose at each step to either update the state and recurse, or finish with a result.

You could represent your state as

```scala
case class State(index: Long, firstMatch: Option[Long])
```

where the `index` is the current index you are about to inspect, and the `firstMatch` is the index where you found your first matching string.

At each step, the algorithm will look at the `index` and check whether it is in-bounds compared to the `max`. If it's out of bounds, it must exit with whatever values it found. If it's in-bounds, grab the string associated with that index, then based on whether that string matches and whether you already found your `firstMatch`, decide whether to continue checking at the next index or return a result.

In order to perform recursion with effects, you're going to need a [`Monad[F]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Monad.html). You can find a lot of articles that explain what a Monad is, but to simplify for the purposes of this answer, it's a thing that knows how to `flatMap` your `F`, and provides the handy [`tailRecM`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Monad.html#tailRecM%5BA,B%5D(a:A)(f:A=%3EF%5BEither%5BA,B%5D%5D):F%5BB%5D) function for doing that flatMapping recursively.

`tailRecM` is a way to represent a recursive algorithm with an `F[_]` effect.

```scala
def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: (A) ⇒ F[Either[A, B]]): F[B]
```

The `a: A` is your initial state, e.g. `State(min, None)`

The `f: A => F[Either[A, B]]` is a function that inspects your current state, then decides whether to recurse, where that decision is done inside an `F` effect. Basically Left means recurse, Right means exit. It's perfect for your situation, where you have a `fetch` method that forces you into an `F` effect.

It returns an `F[B]` when your `f` returns an `F[Right[B]]`, i.e. the end of recursion.

When you write your method, you just have to make sure there is a `Monad` available for the `F` type you're using, so you can use it to call `tailRecM`. In my demo, I put `F` as a type parameter on the method and made `fetch` into an argument, but I suspect in your code, both `findFirstAndLast` and `fetch` are defined inside some class that has the `F` type parameter. Adjust as necessary.

```scala
def findFirstAndLast[F[_]: Monad](
  min: Long, 
  max: Long, 
  str: String, 
  fetch: Long => F[String],
)(implicit F: Monad[F]): F[Option[(Long, Long)]] =
  F.tailRecM(State(min, None)) {
    // if out of bounds, result is None if firstIndex was never found,
    // or `firstIndex -> max` if it was found
    case State(index, firstIndex) if index > max =>
      // note: `f` wants an `F[Either[..]]` so we wrap the either with `F.pure`
      F.pure(Right(firstIndex.map(_ -> max)))
    
    // if in-bounds, fetch the index and decide from there
    case State(index, firstMatch) =>
      F.map(fetch(index)) { 
        case `str` if firstMatch.isEmpty =>
          // found the first match!
          Left(State(index + 1, Some(index)))
          
        case `str` if firstMatch.isDefined =>
          // still matching after first
          Left(State(index + 1, firstMatch))
        
        case other if firstMatch.isDefined =>
          // no longer matching, last match must be previous step
          Right(Some((firstMatch.get, index - 1)))
        
        case other =>
          // still looking for first match
          Left(State(index + 1, None))
      }
  }
```

Example usage with F=SyncIO, but this will work generally with any `F` type that has a `Monad`, e.g. `IO`, `monix.eval.Task`, `Future`, `Option`, etc.

```scala
def exampleFetch(n: Long) = SyncIO { "aabbbcdd".charAt(n.toInt - 1).toString }
val result = findFirstAndLast(1, 8, "b", exampleFetch).unsafeRunSync()
println(result) // Some((3, 5))
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oN0P6e3JQ7WEKkgbxuPLuQ

Comment: Thanks! I've just implemented my methods not using `tailRecM` because I wasn't sure how to use it but this is much better!

Comment: FWIW you can still do your effect-centric recursion with plain old `flatMap`, it's just slightly less convenient than `tailRecM` usually